# How to set password constraints in Gnu/Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, password

1. It contains at least one lowercase letter.
2. It contains at least one digit, which can be in any position except the first and last position.
3. It contains at least one special character (non-alphanumeric: i.e. symbols), which can be in any position except the first and last position.
4. It does not contain sequences of two or more characters from the User ID.
5. It is not a reverse of the user ID nor contain a reverse of the user ID.
6. It does not contain sequences of three or more characters from the previous chosen or given password.
7. It does not contain a sequence of two or more characters more than once within the password (e.g., a39tzb39r).
8. It does not contain a sequence of three or more repeating or sequential numbers or characters in a row (e.g., ax222rm, ct15mnoRx).

Please let me know the command to test these individually.

Comment: Hi! Do you need to generate passwords respecting these rules, or validate that an existing string is conformant?

Comment: This was the stupidest thing I've read today. Sorry. It disqualifies perfectly good passphrases and promotes hard to remember (and therefore short) passwords. Tip: test each condition individually.

Comment: If you do then your users will write their passwords on post-it notes, and stick them to their monitor https://xkcd.com/936/ Teach them how to create good passwords.

Comment: The only way to implement rule 6, is to store clear text passwords. This is a big **NO**: supper bad practice, and probably in violation of gdpr https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation If a user re-uses a password, they will (especially if they are hard to remember). Then if your site gets hacked, then you will leak there password, and it can be used on the other sites.

Comment: This question is very clear, it is just a bad idea (Why the votes to close?).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Unclear due to unspecified "special character ID", "User ID", "number" (`1e10-3` is a number, as is `0xff`), "lowercase letter" (in what alphabet?).

Comment: Are `µ` and `я` acceptable lowercase letters?

Comment: Where is the previous password stored? If this is an assignment, please put the entire text in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Do it with regex

> 1- It contains at least one lowercase letter.

[a-z]

> 2- It contains at least one number, which can be in any position except the first and last position.

.[0-9].

> 3- It contains at least one special character ID, which can be in any position except the first and last position.

.[^a-z0-9A-Z].

> 4- It does not contain sequences of two or more characters from the User ID.

For each 2 char of the id (but I think you mean username (vs full name) as id's are numarical)
((?!$U).)

> 5- It is not a reverse of the user ID nor contain a reverse of the user ID.

U=&(whoami | tac)
((?!$U).)

> 6- It does not contain sequences of three or more characters from the previous chosen or given password.

same as #4

> 7- It does not contain a sequence of two or more characters more than once within the password (e.g., a39tzb39r). 8- It does not contain a sequence of three or more repeating or sequential numbers or characters in a row (e.g., ax222rm, ct15mnoRx).

(.{2,})\1

Then put it all together;

echo -n $PASS | grep -P '[a-z]'  | grep -P '.[0-9].' | grep -P '.[^a-z0-9A-Z].' | grep -vP "((?!$U).)|$ETC"

Expanding the $Us are for loops you should be able to figure out... but as the comments mention the only proper test for secure password is that it is longer than 14 characters (And salted, and preferably restricted the keys for things like SSH )

Comment: Note that `.` matches any character.  So, in step 2, for example, your regular expression would match `000` which has a digit in both first and last position. Also quote `$PASS`.

Comment: Please let me know which regex command should be used to verify.

Comment: @user328010 Seriously, did you even read the answer?